# Can I differentiate settings for controllers per assembly?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-5.0

We need to host several API's in the same ASP.NET Core instance.

Is it possible to have controllers registered with individual settings?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the issue at hand? You can impotr .Net configurations with different paths such as `"ConnectionStrings:Databases:Connection_1"` and `"ConnectionStrings:Databases:Connectio_2"` are differentiated in the lowest level config file. Then you can inject `IOptionsMonitor` and have as a type argument the Relevant nested options class.

Comment: No, I mean the sequence of calls in `ConfigureServices`. For example, some of controllers require Newton.Json as serialization framework, others need System.Text.Json.